# MSDeploy build after win upgrade

Tags: msdeploy

I am doing a msdeploy in the Developer Command Prompt (Admin) and after updating to Win 8.1 Pro, I get this error after running the command.
I did not get this error before the update I got another error USER NOT ADMIN to fix this I had to upgrade so I could create a group and add deploy as Admin.
Please forgive any bad formatting first timer.

```
    >..\..\lib\msdeploy\msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package='Package.zip' -dest:contentPath='test.dev',computerName=localhost,userName=deploy,password=xxxx

Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Exception: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager' threw an exception. ---> System.Exception: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.BuiltInTypesCache' threw an exception. ---> System.Exception: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.MsDeploy.MsDeployProviderBaseProviderFactory' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.IOException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\Bin\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.dll' or one of its dependencies. Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)) ---> System.Exception:Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this part of the error indicates you need to install, repair or uninstall/reinstall the 2012 version of the SQL Server Data Tools:

```
System.IO.IOException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\Bin\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.dll' or one of its dependencies.
```